# Get an element of a tree by path

Tags: python, elementtree

I have some XML file. I know that the element I need is located in some path `\element1\element2\element3`. How do I access it? I only found a way to access an element if it's a child of a root:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('my_xml.xml').getroot()

for child in root.findall('element1'):
    output = child.text
```

Also, I can't just search for `element3` because this name appears in different parts of the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation for `findall`?

```
output = root.findall( './element1/element2/element3' )
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I was looking for